# JavaScript - String Comparision fails even though both are same

Tags: javascript

The following code is failing when I call it with `isValid("()")`. When I debugged it, I see that the comparision fails at `parantheses[parantheses.length - 1] === p` even though both the values are same. Can anyone tell why this is failing ?

```js
var isValid = function(s) {
  const openParantheses = new Set("(", "{", "[");
  const closedParantheses = new Set(")", "}", "]");
  const parantheses = [];

  for (let p of s) {
    if (openParantheses.has(p)) {
      parantheses.push(p);
    } else if (closedParantheses.has(p)) {
      if (parantheses[parantheses.length - 1] === p) {
        parantheses.pop();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (parantheses.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

console.log(isValid("()"))
```

Also when I do console.log(`Inside If - ${parantheses}`) This isnt printing the parantheses array as an array but just giving out values without array notation. Is this something expected ?
Thanks.

Comment: While checking `()`, the `parantheses` array contains only `(`. There is never a `)` in your `parantheses` array. So the comparison will obviously fail.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the two are the same. First loop you go with `"("` finishes, next loop `p` is `)` and the last item in the array is `"("`. So `"(" === ")"` is false

Comment: "even though both the values are same" not on my debugger.

Comment: I just missed that I didnt have closed parantheses and I am comparing ( and ) and checking with equality. Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you never add closed parentheses to the array, the `parantheses[parantheses.length - 1] === p` clause is never true.

I would advise mapping closed parentheses to open ones and using this map to perform your check as I have done below.

Another thing: The Constructor of `Set` takes an array (or any iterable) of values. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set))

```js
var isValid = function(testString) {
  const openParantheses = new Set([
    "(",
    "{",
    "["
  ]);

  const closedParantheses = new Map([
    [')', '('],
    [']', '['],
    ['}', '{'],
  ]);

  const parantheses = [];

  for (const character of testString) {
    if (openParantheses.has(character)) {
      parantheses.push(character);
      continue;
    }

    if (closedParantheses.has(character)) {
      if (parantheses[parantheses.length - 1] === closedParantheses.get(character)) {
        parantheses.pop();
        continue;
      }

      return false;
    }
  }

  return parantheses.length === 0;
};

console.log(isValid("()"));
console.log(isValid("[]"));
console.log(isValid("{}"));

console.log(isValid("([{}])"));
console.log(isValid("({[}])"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I missed that I didnt have closed parantheses. I didnt think it through.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var isValid = function(s) {
  const openParantheses = "({[";
  const closedParantheses = ")}]";
  const parantheses = [];

  for (let p of s) {
    if (openParantheses.indexOf(p) >= 0) {
      parantheses.push(p);
    } else if (closedParantheses.indexOf(p) >= 0) {
      if (openParantheses.indexOf(parantheses[parantheses.length - 1]) ===
        closedParantheses.indexOf(p)) {
        parantheses.pop();
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (parantheses.length > 0) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

console.log(isValid("()"))
```